# Determine $\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{\sqrt{n}\le{r}\le{n}}\sqrt{r^2-n}$ where $n,x\in\Bbb Z$.

Tags: calculus, limits, definite-integrals

Determine $$\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{\sqrt{n}\le{r}\le{n}}\sqrt{r^2-n}$$ where $n,x\in\Bbb Z$.

I converted it into definite integral and got $$n\int_{\frac{1}{\sqrt n}}^{1}\sqrt{x^2-\frac{1}{n}}\;dx$$
Then putting the limits in the evaluated integral and letting $y=\frac{1}{n}$ so limit changes to $y\to 0$, I finally got $$\lim_{y\to 0}\; \frac{\sqrt{1-y}\, - y \log(1+\sqrt{1-y})+y\log\sqrt{y}}{2y}$$ This is coming out to be undefined. All I doubt is the conversion of summation to definite integral. I don’t think that undefined should be the answer. So what can be the correct approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint**.

For big enough $n$ we have $\frac{n}{2} > \sqrt{n}$. Thus
$$
\sum_{\sqrt{n} \le r \le n} \sqrt{r^2 - n} > \sum_{\frac{n}{2} \le r \le n} \sqrt{\frac{n^2}{4} - n} \ge \frac{n}{2} \cdot \sqrt{\frac{n^2}{4} - n}.
$$

Comment: Thanks for the method and confirming the answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

You had the result when you wrote
$$A= \frac{\sqrt{1-y}\, - y \log(1+\sqrt{1-y})+y\log(\sqrt{y})}{2y}$$

The Taylor expansion of the numerator is
$$1+\frac{1}{2} y (\log (y)-1-2 \log
   (2))+\frac{y^2}{8}+\frac{y^3}{32}+O\left(y^4\right)$$ which gives
$$A=\frac{1}{2 y}+\frac{1}{4} (\log (y)-1-2 \log
   (2))+\frac{y}{16}+\frac{y^2}{64}+O\left(y^3\right)$$

Replacing $y$ by $\frac 1n$ gives
$$S_n=\frac{n}{2}-\frac{1}{4} (\log (n)+1+2 \log
   (2))+\frac{1}{16 n}+\frac{1}{64
   n^2}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^3}\right)$$

For $n=10^4$, the truncated series gives
$$S_{10^4}=\frac{31998400040001}{6400000000}-\log \left(10 \sqrt{2}\right)=4997.101$$ while, converted to decimals, the exact result is $4997.601$.